# How do i sync a web-socket object from my service to the component -angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, websocket

I am trying to connect and control a device with an external JavaScript web-socket library. Currently i am able to do this from my angular service. i am not able to pass the connection object to the component. how can i get update in component when the service client object is updated.Can any one help me please

Component code

```
doConnect(data){
    this.submitted = true;
    this.ipaddress = data.ipaddress;
    this.portnumber = data.portnumber;
    this.data = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(this.data);
    if(this.ipaddress===null && this.portnumber===null){
        console.log('Null');
    }else{
    localStorage.setItem("ipaddress", this.ipaddress);
    localStorage.setItem("portnumber", this.portnumber);

    //calling the get connect from component
    this.connectService.getConnect(this.ipaddress,this.portnumber);
    if(localStorage.getItem("clientStatus")=='connected'){
    this._router.navigate(['Master']);
    }else{
    this._router.navigate(['Home']);
    }
    }
}
```

Below is my connectService code

```
getConnect(ipaddress,portnumber){
    console.log('coming');
    var t = ipaddress;
    var p = portnumber;
    console.log(t,p);
    client = new linear.client({transports: [
                                {type: 'websocket',
                                 host: t, port: p}
                               ]});
    client.connect();
    this.getStatusFromMcx();

    var osbervable = Rx.Observable.create (function (obs) {
    // Handle messages  
    client.transport.onopen = obs.onOpen.bind(obs);
    client.onnotify = obs.onNext.bind(obs);
    client.onerror = obs.onError.bind(obs);
    client.transport.onclose = obs.onCompleted.bind(obs);

    // Return way to unsubscribe
    return client.ondisconnect.bind(client);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for my problem. i am sharing this answer because this may help someone who use web socket to connect to external devices. I have used observable with a interval.

```
let stream$ = new Observable(observer => {
    let interval = setInterval(() =>{
         observer.next(client.transport.state);
         observer.complete();
    },1000);
    return() =>{
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    });
    return stream$;
```

then i just subscribed to that method and getting connection details.

```
this.subscription =  this.AppService.getConnect(this.ipaddress,this.portnumber)
    .retry(1)
    .subscribe(
        value =>  {
        console.log("value+++++",value);
        spinner.stop()
        if(value=="disconnected" || value=="connecting"){
            localStorage.setItem("clientStatus", "disconnected");
            spinner.spin(target);
        }else{
            localStorage.setItem("clientStatus", "connected");
            this._router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        }
 ngOnDestroy() {
// prevent memory leak when component is destroyed
this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```